# r write output of for loop into a new column of a data frame

Tags: r, for-loop

I wrote this code to loop through an existing dataframe (blatt2). I would like to create the new data frame (blatt3) where i write the output of the for loop. The loop works, but writes all the results into the same column.
I would like that when the q increases by 1 there should be a new column in the data frame.
So in the end I have the same columns in blatt2 and blatt3.
Here is the code:

```
blatt3 <- data.frame()

for(q in 1:ncol(blatt2)) {
  for(i in seq(1, 790, 3)){
    r <- c(blatt2[i,q], blatt2[i+1,q], blatt2[i+2,q])
    blatt3<- rbind(blatt3,  data.frame(mean(r)))
  }}
```

thanks

Comment: `**r**bind` binds a new **r**ow. Use `**c**bind` to bind a new **c**olumn.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Conventionally, one provides the minimal example data, e.g. `blatt2`, so that your code runs.

Comment: But within inner loop, you are trying to bind things one entry at a time. With your loop structure, you would be better off pre-allocating, `blatt3 = matrix(ncol = ncol(blatt2), nrow = nrow(blatt2) / 3))` and then just assigning `blatt3[(something like your i), q] = mean(r)`. But the loop is skippable....

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more R-like way:

Write a function that does the mean of every `n` items in a vector

```
mean_n = function(x, n) {
    tapply(x, (seq_along(x) - 1) %/% n, mean)
}
```

Apply that function to your data

```
blatt3 = sapply(blatt2, mean_n, n = 3)
```

Demo on built-in data:

```
sapply(mtcars, mean_n, n = 10)
    mpg cyl   disp    hp  drat     wt   qsec  vs  am gear carb
0 20.37 5.8 208.61 122.8 3.538 3.1280 18.581 0.6 0.3  3.6  2.5
1 19.89 6.6 259.25 149.6 3.552 3.6689 18.301 0.4 0.3  3.4  2.9
2 20.39 6.2 228.25 152.6 3.654 2.8633 16.914 0.3 0.5  3.9  2.6
3 18.20 6.0 211.00 222.0 3.825 3.1750 16.600 0.5 1.0  4.5  5.0
```

Generalize it:

```
tapply_n = function(x, n, tFUN = mean, ...) {
    tapply(x, (seq_along(x) - 1) %/% n, tFUN, ...)
}
```

With this version, you can specify `tFUN` to be `mean` or `sum` or whatever else.